# Macro to format a list with arbitrary items

Tags: macros, lists

I'm trying to build a macro that can be used to place an arbitrary number of items in a list

Currently my macro looks like this

```
\newcommand\presentation[6]{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth) - 3em}
    \textbf{#1} \\*
    #2 \smallskip
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-0.15in}
        \item  #3 -- #4 #5 #6
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage} \bigskip\\*
}
```

if `10` input arguments are passed to the macro, I'd like it to do this

```
\newcommand\presentation[6]{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth) - 3em}
    \textbf{#1} \\*
    #2 \smallskip
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-0.15in}
        \item  #3 -- #4 #5 #6
        \item  #7 -- #8 #9 #10
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage} \bigskip\\*
}
```

And so on with additional input variables

Based on [this](https://davidyat.es/2016/07/27/writing-a-latex-macro-that-takes-a-variable-number-of-arguments/) I tried the following but I doesn't seem to work ...

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\present}[6]{%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth) - 3em}
            \textbf{#1} \\*
            #2 \smallskip
            \begin{itemize}
                \setlength{\itemindent}{-0.15in}
                \item  #3 -- #4 #5 #6
}

\newcommand{\checknextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{ 
    \end{itemize} 
    \end{minipage} 
    \bigskip\\*}
}

\newcommand{\gobblenextarg}[4]{ \item  #1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg} -- #2\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg} #3\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg} #4\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}
    {       
        \end{itemize} 
        \end{minipage} 
        \bigskip\\*
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt `\present` doesn't even call `\checknextarg`... In order to simplify the code, I'll assume the number of arguments is of the form 4n + 2, where n is a positive integer. Otherwise, more tests are needed.

Note:

- `\dimexpr` doesn't need parentheses where you put them.
- `\bigskip\\*` doesn't make much sense because `\bigskip` itself is a legitimate breakpoint in most cases (it is one as long as what precedes it is a *non-discardable item* of the vertical list: a box, a whatsit, a mark or an insertion—see TeXbook p. 110, or the *very short* introduction below).
- Also, beware of introducing unwanted spaces.

Regarding your precise problem, you can do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\presentation}[2]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth - 3em}
    \textbf{#1}\\*
    #2\smallskip
    \begin{itemize}
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-0.15in}%
      \checknexttoken
}

\newcommand{\checknexttoken}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\onemoretime}{\finished}}
\newcommand{\onemoretime}[4]{%
  \item #1 -- #2 #3 #4%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\onemoretime}{\finished}%
}

\newcommand*{\finished}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  % \nopagebreak % uncomment if you want to prevent page breaks here
  \bigskip
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\presentation{Title}{Items:}{first}{second}{third}{fourth}

\presentation{Title}{Items:}
  {first}{second}{third}{fourth}
  {fifth}{seventh}{eighth}{ninth}

\presentation{Title}{Items:}
  {first}{second}{third}{fourth}
  {fifth}{seventh}{eighth}{ninth}
  {tenth}{eleventh}{twelfth}{thirteenth}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

In case you need to have an opening brace at the point where you would like the argument grabbing to stop, just insert a `\relax` in your text before the brace so as to prevent a “next round” from being triggered.

## Quick notes on page breaking

When you finish a paragraph in outer vertical mode, each of its lines forms a horizontal box which is therefore a non-discardable item of the main vertical list. Each such line is followed in the main vertical list by vertical material that has “migrated out” (from `\vadjust`, `\insert`, `\mark`...), penalties (for club or widow lines, etc.) and automatically-inserted interline glue. Glue items and penalties are both potential breakpoints, under certain conditions. In the frequent case where a horizontal box representing a paragraph line is immediately followed by a glue item in the main vertical list (glue which could be obtained for instance from a `\bigskip` immediately following the paragraph, or from interline glue automatically added between two consecutive lines), because the box is by definition *non-discardable*, this glue item is a legitimate breakpoint (i.e., a page break may take place right after the box and would normally discard the glue item: glue items are *discardable* ones).

`\nopagebreak` inserts a penalty, which is a discardable item, therefore a `\nopagebreak` immediately preceding something like `\bigskip` that inserts a glue item in the main vertical list, prevents the glue item from being a legitimate breakpoint. `\par` just switches to vertical mode. It doesn't insert anything like a glue item, a box or a penalty by itself.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is a super useful answer

Comment: Glad it helped. I added some precisions regarding page breaking.

Comment: Thanks again ... I'm not sure I completely get the page brake situation with `\bigskip`  When I don't include `\\*` my second `\presentation` gets to the right of my first.  When I include `\\*` it gets typeset below.

Comment: Yes, ``\\`` does cause a line break. If you remove it, no line break occurs. What I was trying to say is that the star form doesn't make sense after a `\bigskip`, because the point of using `\\*` as opposed to ``\\`` is that `\\*` normally prevents page breaking. But if what precedes is `\bigskip`, the `\\*` won't prevent page breaking to occur at the `\bigskip`, so the star is only giving a false sense of security. To avoid unwanted page breaks, one has to make sure there is no legal breakpoint. Adding `\\*` after a breakpoint doesn't prevent anything.

Comment: This is a delicate matter, read chapter 15 of the TeXbook if you want all this to be clear.

Comment: Ahhh ... this make sense ... it wasn't clear to me that you were referring to the start form only.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different approach, with an environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{presentation}[2]
 {\par\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-3em}
  \textbf{#1}\\#2\smallskip
  \begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemindent}{-0.15in}}
 {\end{itemize}\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{2\bigskipamount}}

\newcommand{\present}[4]{\item #1 -- #2 #3 #4}

\begin{document}

\begin{presentation}{Title}{Items:}
\present{first}{second}{third}{fourth}
\present{fifth}{seventh}{eighth}{ninth}
\end{presentation}

\begin{presentation}{Title}{Items:}
\present{first}{second}{third}{fourth}
\end{presentation}

\end{document}
```

This has the advantage of being more “free form”: it doesn't matter if you use blank lines between `\present` lines, so

```latex
\begin{presentation}{Title}{Items:}
\present{first}{second}{third}{fourth}

\present{fifth}{seventh}{eighth}{ninth}
\end{presentation}
```

would typeset the same.

Should you insist on the “variable number of arguments” approach:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\presentation}[2]{
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-3em}
  \textbf{#1}\\#2\smallskip
  \begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemindent}{-0.15in}
  \present
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\present}[4]{
  \item #1 -- #2 #3 #4
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\present}{\end{itemize}\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{2\bigskipamount}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\presentation{Title}{Items:}
  {first}{second}{third}{fourth}
  {fifth}{seventh}{eighth}{ninth}

\presentation{Title}{Items:}
  {first}{second}{third}{fourth}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

[image]